# android connect & communicate over wifi like Airdroid/Kies air/WiFi File Transfer Pro

Tags: android, webserver, android-wifi, wifi-direct, ota

There are many apps which allows you to **communicate over local wifi network**, some of them are [WiFi File Transfer Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smarterdroid.wififiletransferpro), [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid), [Kies air](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.swift.app.kiesair)

i want to do some similar stuff but not getting from where to start, any pointers will be appreciated..

**Edit**: do i need to run local web server for achieving this??

some screenshots of above mentioned app are below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]